# Firebase server-side logic when a user loses their connection

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, server-side, multiplayer

Quick question. I'm using Firebase to make a multiplayer iOS game. If a user is participating in a game, and suddenly their iPhone blows up or the internet goes out for hours or is otherwise dead, I want them to be removed from the game since they can no longer play. If the phone, being dead, cannot tell Firebase to remove the user from the game, is there something I can setup server-side to check if a player is no longer sending data for an extended period of time and then remove them from the game? It's the nature of this game that players are constantly updating the realtime database, so keeping tabs on who is not updating their data would be an easy way to tell if someone's phone just fell off a cliff.

I suppose Player A could check if Player B was no longer updating the game data and remove them from the game, but if both Player A and Player B have their phones burst into flames at the same time, that peer-checking no longer works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *If the phone, being dead, cannot tell firebase to remove the user from the game, is there something I can setup server-side to check if a player is no longer sending data for an extended period of time and then remove them from the game?*

Check this [Detect if Firebase connection is lost/regained](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11351689/4625829) post. I think the link there is directing towards the legacy and this is the [new link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-presence) counterpart.

> *..if both Player A and Player B have their phones burst into flames at the same time, that peer-checking no longer works.*

Shouldn't you just create something like a *Room* where the list of players go into and check the number of currently remaining players using what was mentioned in the above post?

Comment: The onDisconnect stuff in the Managing Presence section looks appropriate. Thanks.