# Create user registration with custom form in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

Currently I have small project using react native and I am using Firebase as backend. I have registration form with more than two fields (name, phone num, gender, etc), but with Firebase we can only register a user with email and password. So, my question is how I can save other information of user and later how I would retrieve that information?

Comment: Since the email is unique, you can store other data on firebase database including the email. So once user is successfully signin, you can use the same email to fetch all necessary details from the firebase database (Cloud Firestore in this scenario)

Comment: The common approach is to store the additional information in a database, such as Cloud Firestore or the Realtime Database. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/42735452, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46657503

Answer (score 3):

On your backend you can create 'users' collection and save it after registering a user

```
  const data = {
    email: 'email',
    password: 'password'
  }

  firebase.auth().createUser(data)
    .then((userRecord) => {

      var uid = userRecord.uid;

      return firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid)
        .set({
          user_uid: uid,
          gender: '',
          ...
        })

    })
```

and later you can use doc id to retrieve extra information

```
firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).get()
```