# Firebase - Is it possible to have a "Cloud Listener" for app connection status?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an Android game which requires the user to be online while playing. I'd like to detect if a game was interrupted while playing ( the internet connection was lost \ the device was turned off, etc...),and if it was -  this should be considered as a loss for the user, and be written in the database.  **The only thing I have in mind for now is to save this loss offline, and update it when the user goes back online.**

---

I know I can detect app connection status like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351689/detect-if-firebase-connection-is-lost-regained), but it doesn't help be because I can only execute offline operations after this. I also know I can listen to writing events in the database like [this](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/07/cloud-functions-realtime-database.html), but it doesn't help me, because no child in being updated after the game is interrupted.

---

**My question is: Is there a way to write a Cloud Function which can listen to specific app connection status?** If there is no such a way, what are the other options I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `onDisconnect()` handler. This is a piece of code you run while the app is connected, that sets an operation for the server to run when it detects that the app has disconnected.

A simple example of this from the documentation:

> ```
> DatabaseRef presenceRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("disconnectmessage");
> // Write a string when this client loses connection
> presenceRef.onDisconnect().setValue("I disconnected!");
> ```

But I recommend that you read the full [documentation on managing presence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-presence) for more examples.

With this you can have a Cloud Function trigger on the operation of the `onDisconnect` handler and then update the game status.

Note that it may take a few minutes before the server detects the lost connection in case of a non-clean disconnect.