# How to detect if Firebase connection is online/offline - Unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

The only solution I found online was for Android- not for Unity- by listening to `('.info/connected')`
like here- [Detect if Firebase connection is lost/regained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351689/detect-if-firebase-connection-is-lost-regained).

But I tried it and it doesn't work (tried to translate their Android solution to C#)-

```
    DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference(".info/connected");
    connectedRef.ValueChanged += (object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs a) => {
        bool isConnected = (bool)a.Snapshot.Value;
        print("isConnected" + isConnected);
    };
```

When I try my code:

Test #1:

- Connected to the internet- starting the app
- log- `isConnected  = true`
- disconnect from the internet
- a lot of socket errors, no calls to isConnected anymore (still true)

Test #2:

- Disconnected to the internet- starting the app
- log- `isConnected  = false`
- a lot of socket errors
- Connect to the internet
- log- `isConnected  = true`

Which means= listeners don't work on offline mode
and the reason why I get `isConnected  = false` only on test #2 is because the function is being called once on start...

How can I tell when the user isn't connected? It's important because I have to manage everything manually until the user is online again- to update the database.

Comment: What's the problem with the code you shared? What does it print when you're online? And what when you are/go offline?

Comment: I added new information to my question

Comment: Hmmm... the results of test #1 seem unexpected. After a while, the value of `.info/connected` should become `false` in this case. I hope somebody else sees what could be causing this.

Comment: It's because the listeners don't work/call the function when offline mode so it stays true, But for example- on test #1 if I force and call that function Manually - it'll show me that isConnected=false