# Firebase Persistent database on first installation

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

My current application developed in Unity uses Firebase Realtime Database with database persistence enabled. This works great for offline use of the application (such as in areas of no signal).

However, if a new user runs the application for the first time without an internet connection - the application freezes. I am guessing, it's because it needs to pull down the database for the first time in order for persistence to work.

I am aware of threads such as: '[Detect if Firebase connection is lost/regained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351689/detect-if-firebase-connection-is-lost-regained)' that talk about handling database disconnection from Firebase.

However, is there anyway I can check to see if it is the users first time using the application (eg via presence of the persistent database?). I can then inform them they must go online for 'first time setup'?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @frank-van-puffelen's answer, I do not believe that Firebase RTDB should itself cause your game to lock up until a network connection occurs. If your game is playable on first launch without a network connect (ie: your logic itself doesn't require some initial state from the network), you may want to check the following issues:

Make sure you can handle `null`. If your game logic is in a `Coroutine`, Unity may decide to silently stop it rather than fully failing out.

If you're interacting with the database via [Transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/database-reference#class_firebase_1_1_database_1_1_database_reference_1a4b21a7318e923a839b8fcca6ca3e90b0), generally assume that it will run twice (once against your local cache then again when the cache is synced with the server if the value is different). This means that the first time you perform a change via a transaction, you'll likely have a `null` previous state.

If you can, prefer to listen to [ValueChanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/query#valuechanged) over [GetValueAsync](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/query#getvalueasync). You'll always get this callback on your main Unity thread, you'll always get the callback once on registration with the data in your local cache, and the data will be periodically updated as the server updates. Further, if you see @frank-van-puffelen [answer elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486417/firebase-offline-capabilities-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent/34487195#34487195), if you're using `GetValueAsync` you may not get the data you expect (including a null if the user is offline). If your game is frozen because it's waiting on a `ContinueWithOnMainThread` (always prefer this to `ContinueWith` in Unity unless you have a reason not to) or an `await` statement, this could `ValueChanged` may work around this as well (I don't think this should be the case).

Double check your object lifetimes. There are a ton of reasons that an application may freeze, but when dealing with asynchronous logic definitely make sure you're aware of the differences between Unity's GameObject lifecycle and C#'s typical object lifecycle ([see this post](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/16/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it/) and my own on [interacting with asynchronous logic with Unity and Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/07/firebase-and-tasks-how-to-deal-with.html)). If an objects `OnDestroy` is invoked before `await`, `ContinueWith[OnMainThread]`, or `ValueChanged` is invoked, you're in danger of running into null references in your own code. This can happen if a scene changes, the frame after `Destroy` is called, or immediately following a `DestroyImmediate`.

Finally, many Firebase functions have an `Async` and synchronous variant (ex: `CheckDependencies` and `CheckDependenciesAsync`). I don't think there are any to call out for Realtime Database proper, but if you use the non async variant of a function (or if you spinlock on the task completing, including forgetting to `yield` in a coroutine), the game will definitely freeze for a bit. Remember that any cloud product is i/o bound by nature, and will typically run slower than your game's update loop (although Firebase does its best to be as fast as possible).

I hope this helps!

--Patrick

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the Firebase Database API to detect whether its offline cache was populated.

But you can detect when you make a connection to the database, for example by [listening to the `.info/connected` node](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state). And then when that first is set to `true`, you can set a local flag in the local storage, for example in `PlayerPrefs`.

With this code in place, you can then detect if the flag is set in the `PlayerPrefs`, and if not, show a message to the user that they need to have a network connection for you to download the initial data.