# How to track connectivity or online state with the Firebase SDK?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform

I am writing an Electron app and use the Firebase SDK. I am looking for an event or boolean that indicates if the machine is "online".

After I disconnect my development machine from the internet I receive exceptions every few seconds with `net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED` in the console. This means the internals of Firebase are aware that there is no internet connection available. Can I somehow subscribe to this?

For clarification, no user API call of the Firebase SDK raises an exception, they are console output only.

#### Potential workarounds

The web API defines the [window:online](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/online_event) and [window:offline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/offline_event) event but they are both not trustworthy as they might return incorrect values when VPNs or VMs are installed.

There is a second alternative to ping my website every n-seconds, but I don't want to let thousands of machines do that just to see if their clients are online.

Comment: Ouch, I looked this up for hours and just found a solution a minute after I posted this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351689/detect-if-firebase-connection-is-lost-regained

Comment: Which Firebase product are you working with?  Realtime Database or Firestore?  Firebase as a platform doesn't do connection tracking.  Only Realtime Database has a facility that lets you understand if the SDK is connected to the database or not (and even then, just the database, and not connectivity as a whole for the device).

Comment: "Firebase raises exceptions that it is not able to connect to its realtime database anymore" Neither of Firebase's databases should treat the lack of a connection as an error condition, unless you perform an operation like a transaction. Can you edit your question to show the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen My question was misleading. No user API raises an exception, but the console output indicates that Firebase is aware that it can't connect to the Firebase service. I updated my question in the hope to clarify my situation

Comment: @DougStevenson I use Firebase Storage + Firebase Realtime Database

Comment: Cloud Storage has no such indicator.  You already found the relevant question that discusses Realtime Database.  Please also see the documentation:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the confirmation!